# trying to iterate over an xml file to match a result from an xml file used to log in

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, iteration

I have two xml files and thanks to Lawrance I am able to parse the xml details of loged in user to admin_panel now I am trying to iterate over a second xml file that only share unique_ref as a referance as I am a newbie to PHP and xml I am struggling to get the result I want. The log in xml is

```
<MYData>
    <login_details>
        <unique_ref>1-61</unique_ref>
        <login_name>tomme</login_name>
        <login>me</login>
        <password>me</password>
        <file1>Test</file1>
        <file2/>
        <file3/>
        <file4/>
    </login_details>
    <login_details>
        <unique_ref>1-63</unique_ref>
        <login_name>tony</login_name>
        <login>tony</login>
        <password>tony</password>
        <file1>Test1</file1>
        <file2/>
        <file3/>
        <file4/>
    </login_details>
</MYData>
```

and the second xml file for the users images

```
<MYData>
<mydata_images>
<unique_ref>1-61</unique_ref>
 <image1>IMG_0125.JPG</image1>
 <image2>IMG_0122.JPG</image2>
 <stat_date>2013-02-03</stat_date>
 <path_file>C:\DATA\\documents\page_1.pdf</path_file>
</mydata_images>
<mydata_images>
<unique_ref>1-61</unique_ref>
 <image1>IMG_0127.JPG</image1>
 <image2>IMG_0128.JPG</image2>
 <stat_date>2013-04-03</stat_date>
 <path_file>C:\DATA\\documents\page_3.pdf</path_file>
</mydata_images>
<mydata_images>
<unique_ref>1-63</unique_ref>
 <image1>2.THEMOUNT.JPG</image1>
 <image2>1.THE-MOUNT.JPG</image2>
 <stat_date>2013-01-03</stat_date>
 <path_file>C:\DATA\\documents\page_2.pdf</path_file>
</mydata_images>
<mydata_images>
<unique_ref>1-61</unique_ref>
  <image1>IMG_0109.JPG</image1>
  <image2>IMG_0112.JPG</image2>
 <stat_date>2013-05-03</stat_date>
 <path_file>C:\DATA\\documents\page_4.pdf</path_file>
</mydata_images>
</MYData>
```

I'd like to display the images of the logged in user and pdf's  I have tried with array_intersect but I keep getting an error here is the admin_panel that I have been playing with

```
<?php
session_start();
//logout
$mydata2 = simplexml_load_file("xml/mydata_images.xml");
if(isset($_GET['logout'])){unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);session_destroy();}


//check login
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']) && $_SESSION['logged_in']==true){
    //json decode user details from session into an array
    $user_details = json_decode($_SESSION['user_details'],true);
    $id = json_decode($_SESSION['id'],true);
    //debug your values
    $unique_ref =$mydata2->mydata_images;
    echo $unique_ref;
    $result = array_intersect($user_details,$unique_ref );
    $unique_ref =$user_details["unique_ref"];
    //foreach ($mydata2 as $unique_ref => $result){
        //print "$unique_ref = $result\n";
       // print_r($result);
    //}
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($user_details,true).'</pre>';
    echo $id;
    echo $user_details["login"];
    echo $unique_ref;
    echo $result;
    /*
    Array
    (
        [unique_ref] => 1-61
        [login_name] => tomme
        [login] => me
        [file1] => Test
        [file2] => Array
            (
            )

        [file3] => Array
            (
            )

        [file4] => Array
            (
            )

    )
    */

    echo '<a href="?logout">logout</a>';
}else{
    exit(header("Location: ./login.php"));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using xpath to select the right element that contains your images

```
$mydata_images = $mydata2->xpath('/MYData/mydata_images[unique_ref="1-61"]');
```

Will now contain the simplexml result(s) matching by your ref element

Comment: Hi Scuzzy how would I make your code more dynamic would changing

Comment: $mydata_images = $mydata2->xpath('/MYData/mydata_images[unique_ref="1-61"]'); to something like $mydata_images = $mydata2->xpath('/MYData/mydata_images[unique_ref="<?php echo $unique_ref;?>"]'); or is there a much better way of achieving this

Comment: $mydata_images = $mydata2->xpath('/MYData/mydata_images[unique_ref="' . $somevargoeshere . '"]'); [see this link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) on how to work with strings

Comment: Thank you Scuzzy that will make life a lot easier I've book marked that link so I  can practice